# Maven rpm plugin does not overwrite files

Tags: maven, rpm, rpm-maven-plugin

I have below configuration in pom.xml file for rpm. I want to copy a jar at specific folder when rpm runs. The code is as below in pom.xml:

```
<mapping>
   <directory>/var/lib/abc</directory>
   <filemode>777</filemode>
   <username>aaa</username>
   <groupname>aaa</groupname>
   <sources>
       <source>
          <location>/opt/lib/temp.jar</location>
       </source>
   </sources>
</mapping>
```

The same configuration I have in another pom file for another rpm.

The problem is, when I run the any rpm first it created the folder, copy the file.

Working as expected but I run another rpm file, it generated error that the files are already present and not overwrite those file.

I just want to know, is there any way to overwrite those file or any way avoid the error if the files are already present to that location.

Thanks,
Atul

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been resolved.

There is strange fix I did:

```
<filemode>777</filemode>
```

This line I have to added in pom file, where it was missing.

I thought, it would allow me, as the directoy is already created.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're doing, but this is _probably_ a bad idea. Permission 777 on a globally-installed file is _always_ a security risk.

Comment: @AaronD.Marasco , yes you are right. The solution I have found to solve the problem given here. We have already changed those permissions as per the requirement.  As per the requirement, user change the permissions and use it.